# SMS to my website!

Tags: java

I want people to be able to send SMSs to a short code in my country which will be redirected to my website so that the site can receive the SMS and can also be read by anyone who is logged on the site.

But i have no idea how to go about this. Your suggestions are highly welcome. Help please me.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SMS Gateway - General Questions on SMS-Website Communication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663604/sms-gateway-general-questions-on-sms-website-communication)

Comment: This will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570410/how-to-send-sms

Answer (score 0):

[Twilio](http://blog.twilio.com/2010/02/introducing-a-new-api-twilio-sms.html) has a nifty API

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an [SMS gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway), for example these guys (random Google result) - http://www.ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=324.

Answer (score 0):

There are many providers of SMS services out there. You normally pay a monthly fee for incoming traffic and then a fixed amount for example for every 1000 SMS you need to send.

Here is an example of one of them http://www.clickatell.com/ Note that I have never used them and don't recommend them in any way. You want to find a company operating in your local country.

Your second alternative is to get one of those 3G Data Modems and hook up to the server. Some of those modems provides an API to send and receive SMS. You will then need a fully working SIM, might be cheaper for lower volumes but slower and less stable solution usually.